# How to resolve an issue with IntegratedWebLogicServer in JDeveloper?

Tags: java, jdeveloper

the version of JDeveloper I am using is 12.2.1.4.0 and the JDK version I am using for the application is Java 1.8.0.202.

The issue I am currently having is whenever I am trying to run an application within JDeveloper I am getting this error code:

```
*** Using HTTP port 7101 ***
*** Using SSL port 7102 ***
C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[Starting IntegratedWebLogicServer.]
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
Files was unexpected at this time.
Process exited.
[IntegratedWebLogicServer terminated.]
```

Could someone please explain how I may resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is to use JDK 1.8.0_101 as this older version is proven to work with JDev 12.2.1.4.
If you have access to support you should download the latest bundle patch for 12.2.1.4 and then use the current JDK 1.8.0_2xx.